# Как удалить второй класс у DOM элемента?

Tags: javascript, dom

Есть код к примеру такой:

```
<div class="info">
 <i id="curr" class="first second"></i>
</div>
```

Как мне удалить 2-ой класс у элемента  ?


Но мне необходимо учитывать то что **имя второго класса будет изменяться динамически** и .classList.remove('second') мне не подходит

Comment: а просто попробовать getAttribute("class", "first"); ? или document.getElementById("curr").className="first";

Comment: `elem.className = elem.className.split(' ')[0]`

Comment: порядок классов в строке может быть любым, почему ты думаешь, что тот класс, который нужно будет удалить будет стоять на втором месте, а не на первом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант 1**, простейший (берем класс по индексу 1, и удаляем его):

```js
const el = document.querySelector('#curr');
el.classList.remove(el.classList.item(1));

console.log(el.className);
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <i id="curr" class="first second third"></i>
</div>
```

---

**Вариант 2**, <s>мощнейший</s> *[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)* для классов (ну а почему бы и нет :) ):

```js
console.log(classSplice('#curr', 1, 2, 'foo', 'bar'));

function classSplice(selector, ...args) {
  const el = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (!el) return;
  const classes = el.className.split(/\s+/);
  classes.splice(...args);
  return (el.className = classes.join(' '));
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <i id="curr" class="first second third fourth"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем *splice*, так как возвращает не массив удаленных элементов, а новый `className`, но так имхо удобнее...

Answer (score 0):

Вы спокойно можете получить строку классов, и из нее выбрать все необходимое.

Для примера добавил css классов, чтобы было видно.

```js
var classList = document.getElementById('curr').className.split(/\s+/);
document.getElementById('curr').className = classList[0];
```

```css
.first{
  background-color: red;
}
.second{
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
 <i id="curr" class="first second" style = "width: 50px; height: 50px; position: absolute"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Удаляет именно второй (по порядку) класс, а не все классы после первого.

```js
function removeClass(position) {
  const element = document.getElementById('curr');
  removeClassOnPosition(element, position);
  showCurrentClasses(element);
}

function removeClassOnPosition(element, position = 0, count = 1) {
  var classList = Array.from(document.getElementById('curr').classList);
  classList.splice(position, count);
  document.getElementById('curr').className = classList.join(' ');
}

function showCurrentClasses(element) {
  currentClasses.textContent = element.classList;
}

showCurrentClasses(document.getElementById('curr'));
```

```css
.first {
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.third {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div id="curr" class="first second third" style="width: 50px; height: 50px">text</div>
</div>
<div id="currentClasses"></div>
<button onclick="removeClass(1)">remove second class</button>
```